# jQuery click handler code not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile

I've been trying to figure this out and have found multiple "solutions" on here (and other places), but nothing seems to work for me. Am I overlooking something?

Everything works fine on desktop but on mobile (specifically iOS Safari) the click event code does NOT work.

** To clarify....the click event IS firing....if I throw in an alert, it triggers. But the DOM is not manipulated. Again, this is ONLY on mobile. The DOM manipulation code works 100% on desktop.

This is a WordPress site which is why I have to workaround no conflict mode. Here's my code below...

HTML

```
<button id="add-ingredient" class="add-button" style="cursor: pointer;">Add</button>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('#add-ingredient').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var lastIngredient = $(this).prev('[class^="ingredient-').attr('class');

            var x = lastIngredient.replace('ingredient-', '');
            x = parseInt(x) + 1;
            var html = '<div class="ingredient-'+ x + '">' +
                    '<input type="text" name="recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][amount]" id="amount" placeholder="amount" value="<?php echo $recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][amount]; ?>" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][unit]" id="unit" placeholder="unit" value="<?php echo $recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][unit]; ?>" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][ingredient]" id="ingredient" placeholder="ingredient" value="<?php echo $recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][ingredient]; ?>" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][notes]" id="notes" placeholder="notes" value="<?php echo $recipe_ingredients['+ x + '][notes]; ?>" />' +
                '</div>';
            $(this).before(html);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: when you say the "click event does not work", do you mean that it never triggers the callback? If you add a `alert(event)` or `console.log(event)` before `event.preventDefault()` do you see a response?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. 

The callback IS triggered but the DOM is not manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out that I had an error in my jQuery code where I was using a bad selector. Turns out Chrome was allowing it to pass through where others browsers (iOS Safari) were not. I found the error here...

```
var lastIngredient = $(this).prev('[class^="ingredient').attr('class');
```

The issue is in the class^="ingredient..... selector. Notice I didn't close the [ ]. Code should be as follows....

```
var lastIngredient = $(this).prev('[class^="ingredient"]').attr('class');
```

Doing that made everything work fine on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `event.preventDefault();`, the callback should be executed.

If you want to prevent default behavior, I would recommend listening for a `touchstart` event:

```
$('#add-ingredient').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Tried that setup and it didn't work. It just triggers a form submission without the event.preventDefault. 

Like I said, mobile safari triggers the callback but the DOM manipulation doesn't happen. If I add an alert into the top of the callback code, that triggers...but that's it.